# How identify the next value based on set criteria | mySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a SELECT query to select all names where TestID is 34 but also identify the next name on the list is where the `Active` row is 0 and the previous Active row is 2, 3 or 4 but not 1 or 0.

I would like to identify these results in a separate *"virtual"* column called `Status` where all rows where `Active` is 2, 3 or 4 is *"Done"* and the next row after the very last `Active` 2, 3 or 4 is *"Next"* every other row after can be identified as just blank.

What kind of logic can used to determine these kinds of results?

Comment: Please read through this post and edit your question accordingly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/460557

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, of course I try to follow best practices when posting - is there anything in particular that is not clear? It is difficult for me to attempt developing a query as my attempts are just simple SELECTS

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x I think you should be able to do this with the LAG() or LEAD() window functions.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am using MySQL 8.0, can you please show and example of a possible way to achieve this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know window functions well. And SO is not a code-writing service, you're expected to show your attempt and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: So first, don't use images when asking about SQL questions. Whoever is willing to help will need to use your data locally to test out the solution, second, because of the same reason provide the SQL statements for one to use it. Third, as Barmar pointed out we are not a coding service you are expected to show some effort. 
Please, again, read through the post I shared and follow the steps that apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
/* This CTE is just to provide mock data to test the query */
WITH table_name (`ID`, `TestID`, `Name`, `Active`) AS (
    SELECT 1, 34, 'Jackson', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 34, 'Jim', 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 34, 'Jerry', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 34, 'Jackie', 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 34, 'John', 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 34, 'Kaleb', 0
)
SELECT
    `Name`,
    `Active`,
    CASE
        /* When current row Active is 2, 3 or 4 then Status is Done */
        WHEN `Active` IN (2, 3, 4) THEN 'Done'
        /* When current row Active is 0 and previous row Active is 2, 3 or 4 then Status is Next */
        WHEN `Active` = 0 AND LAG(`Active`) OVER (ORDER BY `ID`) IN (2, 3, 4) THEN 'Next'
        /* Otherwise Status is an empty string */
        ELSE ''
    END AS `Status`
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `TestID` = 34
ORDER BY `ID` ASC;
```

[Read more about window functions here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will read more about Lag and window functions.

Comment: Your welcome. In future, including table declarations and insert statements, so people can quickly build test datasets, will get answers quicker. When you post images we have to put in more effort to be able to help. Also, including example data in markdown tables is helpful. The more effort you show when asking your question, the more likely you are to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need those blank `status` rows, If that's the case and you just need to know which one is going to be the next. And to achieve this we need to arrange the data in some order [let's use `id` for that]
The following snippet can help

```
select names, active,
'Done' as status
from <TableName> 
where TestID = 34 and active in (2,3,4) order by id 
union all 
select * from (
 select names, active,
 'Next' as status
 from <TableName> 
 where TestID = 34 and active in (0,1) order by id limit 1 
) next
```

However, if blank status rows are also require then we can add one more union to achieve it

```
union all 
select * from (
 select names, active,
 '' as status
 from <TableName> 
 where TestID = 34 and active in (0,1) order by id limit <aBigNumber> offset 2
) blank

aBigNumber can be 18446744073709551615 (max Of Unsigned BIGINT)
```

then final SQL will look like

```
select names, active,
'Done' as status
from <TableName> 
where TestID = 34 and active in (2,3,4) order by id 
union all 
select * from (
 select names, active,
 'Next' as status
 from <TableName> 
 where TestID = 34 and active in (0,1) order by id limit 1 
) next
union all 
select * from (
 select names, active,
 '' as status
 from <TableName> 
 where TestID = 34 and active in (0,1) order by id limit 18446744073709551615 offset 2
) blank
```

Why SubQuery: Because we can not use `limit` in between of `union`

Comment: To clarify I still need those blank status rows to be there, it’s just important for them to be blank as I have other logic in the select query

Comment: I have already implemented the scenario!! Hope it will help